# Анимированный переход по ссылкам с адаптивным отступом от шапки

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, responsive, animate

Есть скрипт, который анимирует переход по якорным ссылкам с верхним отступом 200 от фиксированной шапки.

```
$(".menu").on("click","a#anchor", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
     top = $(id).offset().top;
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top -200}, 500);
});
```

При адаптиве шапка уменьшается, соответственно отступ тоже нужно сделать меньше.
Помогите пожалуйста, если возможно более подробно, потому что у меня вообще не получается решить эту проблему.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените `200` на высоту вашей шапки, узнавая ее в момент клика:

```
$(".menu").on("click","a#anchor", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
      top = $(id).offset().top,
      height = $(".header").height();
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top - height}, 500);
});
```